# Prove that there exist a constant $b/w f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

$∀x∈\mathbb{R}\>0, ∃a∈ \mathbb{R}, a∈[f(x), g(x)] ∨ a∈[g(x), f(x)]$
where, $g(x) = x, f(x) = \log(x)$.

$\iff ∀x∈ \mathbb{R}>0, ∃a∈ \mathbb{R}, a∈[\log x, x] ∨ a∈[x, \log x].$

How would you prove this?

Geometrically, I know that $x > \log(x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.
And there always exist a constant, $a$, $b/w$ them, but I'm not sure how to quite prove it.

Idea 1: $|x - \log(x)| > 0$ => never intersect => there is always a constant $b/w$ them.

Idea 2: Let $a = (\log x + x)/2$, but how would you prove the inequality.
Could I just show that:

$\log x \leq (\log(x) + x) / 2 $
and
$$(\log(x) + x / 2) \leq x$$ holds? Vice versa for other inequality.

Comment: Is E$=\in$, R$=\Bbb R$, R+$=\Bbb R_{>0}$, V$=\lor$ etc.?

Comment: Yes. I will change it right away